Present Perfect Continuous + Until + Present Perfect Simple - for an actions that have taken place some times before?
Two friends have a casual conversation over a cup of coffee:

Jim: "Last week I was at this birthday party where I drank a full bottle of Absinthe; it was crazy! Tell me, have you ever drunk a bottle of Absinthe before?"
Matthew: "No, but I remember a few times that/when I've been drinking it until I've felt terribly sick, maybe after three or four shots, because It's really too strong for me."

Is this answer grammatically correct  and which one of the prepositions should I use here?
I know that it's unnecessary complicated but the purpose of it is for me to learn whether I can use the Present Perfect Continuous this way. The answer sounds good to me but how about you?
The example is not that good maybe but I hope that you understand what I'm asking here!


I remember a few times I drank it until I felt terribly sick.

NOW:

I've been drinking it and now I feel terribly sick.

The present perfect continuous must be used at a time of speaking that is in the present time and that does not refer to the past. It starts in the past (not long ago or longer ago) but lasts until the time of speaking.

Remember this: Senator Kaine: I have heard Hillary Clinton say over and over again, when I've been sitting next to her and when I've watched her on TV that, with respect to the e-mails, "I made a mistake and I've learned something and I wouldn't do it again.", and I've heard her apologize.?

You answer: All of those are unspecified as to when they occurred. A speaker referring to an unspecified time in the past in relation to the present time of speaking often makes use of the present perfect and present prefect continuous (for an action verb) precisely because it is not a finished or past action with a time adverbial, stated or implied.

So, if in the example above the PPC can be used, why in my example can't? In my example, it is also unspecified as to when  I've drunk Absinthe. A few times before, when I've been drinking Absinthe, I've been drinking it until I've felt sick, three to four shots maximum, never more than that because It's too strong. Could you explain this to me? Is this sentence correct?

@MickeyQ It is not about finished or unfinished. It's about the relationship to the time of speaking in the present.

Exactly! So, why the PPC works in the example in the comment while in the OP doesn't? I can't see any difference!

@MickeyQ Because "a few times"works with simple past, not with past perfect continuous. We don't say: I've been going a few times.

Would it work with the present perfect: "I remember a few times I've drunk it until I've felt terribly sick." or not? Does "I remember" suggests specific occasions on which I drank it?

@MickeyQ I am done with this question. :) Repeat: Because "a few times"works with simple past, not with past perfect continuous.

I never mentioned the past perfect continuous! But, anyway, thank you for your time!

N.B. - Lambie was talking about the present perfect continuous, NOT the past perfect continuous.
